# Trouble creating user on mysql

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Im running a class assignment where I need to create a user on mysql, but I keep getting an error when I type the command in...

The command I used is create user 'www'@'localhost' identified by 'wwwUSERpass';

I keep getting an error message that says 
"Error 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'www'@'localhost'

What does this mean?...Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Chances are that the user already exists and you should try to `drop` it first and see if that solves it.  Otherwise, at the very least search the error message on Google and try a few things.  If still unsuccessful, you could add those details, preferably on stackoverflow.com which is programming related.

Answer (score 0):

@Julie Pelletier is probably right. You are trying create a user which already exists. To check:

1) Login to mysql with root user.

Enter:

```
use mysql;
```

2) Enter:

```
select * from user where User='www'\G;
```

If this query return a row it means you have the user already created and can login to mysql with the credentials you created it with. Which is most probably the case.

If you forgot the credentials or want to re-create the user login as root in mysql cli and again follow step 1 and than enter:

```
delete from user where User='www';
```

and then:

```
flush privileges;
```

Remember if deleting user run "flush privileges". Refer to this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555328/error-1396-hy000-operation-create-user-failed-for-jacklocalhost

than re-enter the user creation command. All this is pretty simple and could have been solved with minimal effort on your end.